# Static files of drf-yasg is not found on production server #835

Tags: django-rest-framework, drf-yasg, django-rest-swagger

**Static file not found**

I'm using **Django 4.0.2, drf-yasg is 1.21.4** and **django-rest-swagger 2.2.0**

I have installed all of the above mentioned things and Swagger is working fine on my local system and everything working as expected.

But when I have pushed this code on the server (production) I'm getting a file not found error.

I have also attached a snapshot for the reference.

[image]

I tried a few things related to static file location like **STATICFILES_DIRS** and **collectstatics** but it's not working.

Also tried to changing the URLs and path but still getting the same error.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: The output for "manage.py collectstatic" was successful?

Comment: Yes @RobertoAssunçãoFilho

Answer (score -1):

You should install whitenoise, the problem will be solved

pip install whitenoise

you should check the documentation https://whitenoise.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).